# How to use an array of y values to render a 2D top-down Java game?

Tags: java, 2d, rendering

I'm fairly new to the world of coding, and there's probably a simple solution here. I made this array (the actual one is more complex since it includes everything I have so far) for the y values of every object that needs to be rendered, but I don't know how to use it to keep track of which y values correspond to which object in order to draw them from lowest y value to highest y value.

```
int [] yValues = {deer.getY(), sprite.getY(), tree.getY()+150};
    Arrays.sort(yValues);
```

The deer just randomly walks around, and the player (sprite) is controlled by arrow keys. I added to the y value of the trees so that characters that walk around would stay behind them.

Right now I've hard-coded the layering, depending on when the sprite is in front of or behind the tree (hair and skin y positions are dependent on the y position of the sprite, which is why I didn't include them in the yValues array).

```
//Printing order
    if (sprite.getY() < tree1.getY()+150) { //if the player is behind the tree

        g2d.drawImage(deer.getImage(), deer.getX(), deer.getY(), this);

        g2d.drawImage(sprite.getImage(), sprite.getX(), 
            sprite.getY(), this);
        g2d.drawImage(skin.getImage(), sprite.getX(), 
                sprite.getY(), this);
        g2d.drawImage(hair.getImage(), sprite.getX(), 
                sprite.getY(), this);

        //the tree is drawn after everything else   
        g2d.drawImage(tree.getImage(), tree.getX(), tree.getY(), this);
    }


    if (sprite.getY() >= tree1.getY()+150) { //if the player is in front of the tree

        //the tree is drawn before everything else
        g2d.drawImage(tree.getImage(), tree.getX(), tree.getY(), this); 

        g2d.drawImage(deer.getImage(), deer.getX(), deer.getY(), this);

        g2d.drawImage(sprite.getImage(), sprite.getX(), 
            sprite.getY(), this);
        g2d.drawImage(skin.getImage(), sprite.getX(), 
                sprite.getY(), this);
        g2d.drawImage(hair.getImage(), sprite.getX(), 
                sprite.getY(), this);
    }
```

From here, how would I use the yValues array to order the drawing?

[I found this post helpful to what I'm trying to do] ([Java Slick2d image depth/layering](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/111697/java-slick2d-image-depth-layering)).

[image: The above code works for the tree]
[image]

[image: But not for other objects, like this deer:]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I figured out and it works, but Martin's answer is probably a lot more efficient.

I went ahead and used the array of y values that I made, and then below it made a bunch of code segments like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < yValues.length; i++) {
if (sprite.getY() == yValues[i]) {

            g2d.drawImage(sprite.getImage(), sprite.getX(), sprite.getY(), this);}
//And so on for each sprite.                     
}
```

Comment: i core you hit the same idea - i didn't make it in time to provide the complete answer, but i'm glad you found a way!!!!

Answer (score 1):

instead of trying to identify the drawing order for each sprite itself you should create a proper drawing order first of.

```
List<Sprite> sprites;
Comparator<Sprite> topLeftComparator;

void draw(Graphics graphics){
    sprites.sort(topLeftComparator); //create proper drawing order first
    for (Sprite sprite: sprites){
        sprite.draw(graphics); //then draw all sprites
    }
}
```

### Details

let's assume you have a class (better: an interface) named `Sprite`. That `Sprite` allows you to set the position of the sprite (and read it back) and to draw it

```
interface Sprite {

    //set & read back position
    void setPostion(int x, int y);
    int getX();
    int getY();

    //draw
    void draw(Graphics graphics); 

}
```

you can now create and position all Sprites that you want to draw. Add them to your list:

```
Sprite tree, player;
List<Sprite> sprites;
...
//set postion
tree setPosition(2,4);
player.setPosition(2,3);

//and add to the list
sprites.add(tree);
sprites.add(player);
```

then you simply sort that list and draw your sprites according to the order of the list (as mentioned above).

### Sorting

the magic happens when you sort the list. The sorting algorithm that is used sorts the sprites first by **y-value** (aka each row) and than by **x-value** (by column). That results in an top/left->bottom/right order.

```
Comparator<Sprite> topLeftComparator = new Comparator<Sprite>() {

    @Override
    public int compare(Sprite s1, Sprite s2) {
        int compareValueOfRow = Integer.compare(s1.getY(), s2.getY());
        if (compareValue == 0){ //0 means y is equal for both
            //the return according to x-pos
            return Integer.compare(s1.getX(), s2.getX()); 
        }else{
            return compareValue;
        }
     }

};
```

Comment: How would such comparator function look like? Since OP is at a beginner-level of programming, it might help to show an example of such function.

Comment: Sorry for such a short answer, i was in a hurry when i wrote that answer. I'll add these details, when i'm back at my office

Comment: @Daniel_1985 sorry for being so late ^_^ the OP helped even itself =)